# mongodb design: atomic updates on tree hierarchy

Tags: mongodb, database-design, transactions, tree

I am working on a page hierarchy (mongodb document):

```js
{
    _id: 012,
    content: "lorem ipsum whatever...",
    subpages: [123,234,345,456], // page ids
}
```

The page structure will actually be highly dynamic, so many updates will occur simultaneously with many reads. However, every change (like moving a subpage into another page) requires at least 2 update operations:

```js
// move 123 into page 234
db.pages.update({"_id":012}, {$pull:{"subpages":123}});
db.pages.update({"_id":234}, {$push:{"subpages":123}});

// delete page 345
db.pages.update({"_id":012}, {$pull:{"subpages":345}});
db.pages.remove({"_id":345});
```

Is there a way to perform (or design the model to enable performing) operations like moving a page or deleting a page atomically (to prevent the state of the hierarchy going bad)?

**Notes**

One possibility I'm looking at right now is manually locking the documents by adding a "lockedBy" field to every page, which will contain a transaction ID. But I don't like the idea of continuously polling if I want a second locking operation to block until the first locking operation completes (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2244). Also, since locking is managed by the application, if the application (or one instance of it) goes down for whatever reason during a locking operation, the documents need to be unlocked somehow, without affecting other transactions.

I've also looked at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB and it seems that none of the examples (except for the single document one) solves this problem. However, I would like to avoid putting the entire hierarchy into a single document, because of the 16MB document size constraint and the difficulty of moving pages around (basically I need to upsert the entire document for every change).

**Updates**

We hope to support up to 10000 subpages for a page. The IDs for pages are at least 6 characters long. With that in mind, we moved from mySQL because we need to keep track of the order of the sub-pages. Since mySQL doesn't have array structures, the only way to do that is to use a position column. When pages are moved around frequently, it is expensive to calculate average positions and re-index when the position value becomes too long. Also, if we wanted to put a comma separated list of ids into a column, we would have to use a TEXT column (read from disk) rather than a VARCHAR (which has a limit of 65536 chars) in order to support 10000 sub-pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no transactions. There are atomic operations but they only operate on one document at a time. I'd say, your only choice for a reliable update is to put the whole hierarchy into one document. I wouldn't worry too much about running over document limit: 16MB is a LOT of integers.

Also I think, this is an example where a "regular" relational transactional database is much more useful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply - regarding the document limit, we can easily hit that limit because the content of the pages may be very large (unless you are suggesting to put the content into a different document). We also moved from a relational database because we need to keep maintain the ordering of the subpages and it is difficult to do so without an array structure (we originally calculated the average position of two adjacent positions when moving a page - very expensive to fetch multiple records ordered by position and occasionally reindex). Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Exactly, you can store content separately from hierarchy. About ordering: I don't see any ordering in your mongodb schema. You just $push to the end. You can easily achieve the same with RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I just used push to simplify the example. Sorry for the confusion. We are actually reading the array, adding the page, and rewriting the entire array using the "update if current" method (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22).

Comment: @andy: I suggest that you look at [Redis](http://redis.io). It can handle such tasks very-very quickly and it has transactions (kinda).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but we've invested a lot of time into mongodb and will stick with it for now. Maybe I'll try out redis for my next project. I'll go with your answer as it seems to be the only way (though I am still wondering if there are any pitfalls with this method). Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, there's a pitfall. The whole hierarchy is in one freaking document! You have to make sacrifices :)